# how to configure two instances of Kafka StreamsBuilderFactoryBean in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Using spring-boot-2.1.3, spring-kafka-2.2.4, I want to have two streams configurations (e.g. to have different application.id, or connect to different cluster, etc).  So I defined the first stream configuration pretty much according to the docs, then added a second one, with a different name, and a second StreamsBuilderFactoryBean (also with a different name):

```
@Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kStreamsConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "myappId1000");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    //...
    return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
}

@Bean(name = "myKappConfig")
public KafkaStreamsConfiguration myKafkaAppIdConfiguration() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "myappId9999");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    //...
    return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
}

@Bean(name = "myKappConfigStreamBuilder")
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean myAppStreamBuilder(
        @Qualifier("myKappConfig") KafkaStreamsConfiguration myKafkaAppIdConfiguration) {
    return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(myKafkaAppIdConfiguration);
}
```

However, when I try to run the app, I get:

> Parameter 0 of method kafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer in
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration
>   required a single bean, but 2 were found:
>     - &defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder: defined by method 'defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder' in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.class]
>     - &myKappConfigStreamBuilder: defined by method 'myAppStreamBuilder' in class path resource
>   [com/teramedica/kafakaex001web/KafkaConfig.class]

because the code in the spring-boot autoconfigure does:

```
@Bean
public KafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer kafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer(
        StreamsBuilderFactoryBean factoryBean) {
    return new KafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer(this.properties, factoryBean);
}
```

Short of replacing the KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration entirely, how do I define more than one StreamsBuilderFactoryBean. Or alternately, how can I change the properties for a given stream?

Comment: as I see, you configured your own `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`, and one was autoconfigured inside `KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration`. in case you need to define two streams builders by your own, maybe you don't need bean from autoconfiguration? so just exclude such auto configuration, or remove `@EnableKafkaStreams`

Comment: You just need to mark one as `@Primary`; boot should probably be a bit more lenient, though.

Comment: The one that should be marked @Primary is defined in KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration, and is spring code, not mine, so I can't mark it (at least not with an annotation on the class, itself).  Alternately, the StreamsBuilderFactoryBean used in In KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration#kafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer could be qualified. But again, not my code.    I could remove EnableKafkaStreams, but then I'm duplicating existing code when I really just want to add.  Seems like I should be able to define more than one config without starting from scratch.

Comment: Sorry - I don't get notifications of comments on your question, only my answer, so I didn't see this. See my reply there; I agree that boot should not barf in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark one factory bean with `@Primary`.

Comment: Is there a way to mark a bean `@Primary` that is defined in existing code?  I would want to mark KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder (spring code) as primary.  Though I guess I could essentially duplicate what that does, mark _that_ as primary, and then add another.  Then the  original bean would just be unused, which is a bit klunky.  I'm wondering if in the end, it might be cleaner to disable the auto configuration and do it myself, as suggested by @VasiliySarzhynskyi.

Comment: You would need to redefine their bean. `>bean would just be unused` no it wouldn't be present at all, it would be replaced by your bean definition. I suggest you open an issue against Boot to ask them to handle your use case more elegantly.

Comment: > You would need to redefine their bean. >bean would just be unused no it wouldn't be present at all, it would be replaced by your bean definition.   I'd also need to remove `EnableKafkaStreams`, since there's no conditional. But I see that's the only bean in there, anyway,

Comment: Just hit the same issue and tried to exclude KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration, but failed with 'The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
 - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration' is that expected? KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration is of package scope.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; if the exclusion doesn't work, it might be a bug in boot; ask a new question with more details or, if you believe it's a bug, open an issue against Boot.

Comment: @Gary Russell Could you elaborate on the solution? In my case it does not work. I redefine `DEFAULT_STREAMS_BUILDER_BEAN_NAME` as `@Primary` and still get `Parameter 0 of method kafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found
 - &defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder: defined by method 'defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder' in class path resource [com/.../MyConfig.class]
 - &snapshotKafkaStreamsBuilder: defined by method 'snapshotKafkaStreamsBuilder' in class path resource [com/../MyConfig.class]`

Comment: Please ask a new question and show your configuraion; code etc is too hard to read in comments.

Comment: Sorry for the mess.. here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359604/cannot-mark-default-streams-config-bean-name-as-primary