# Cannot mark DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME as Primary

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I just upgraded to spring-boot 2.1.3.RELEASE and I cannot have more than one StreamsBuilderFactoryBean because of this new class/ method (`kafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer` requires exactly one `factoryBean`):

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(StreamsBuilder.class)
@ConditionalOnBean(name = 
KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_BUILDER_BEAN_NAME)
class KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration {
 //...
 @Bean
 public KafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer kafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer(
        StreamsBuilderFactoryBean factoryBean) {
    return new KafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer(this.properties, factoryBean);
 }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Parameter 0 of method kafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- &defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder: defined by method 'defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder' in class path resource [com/elsevier/q2c/transaction/snapshot/builder/config/KafkaStreamsConfig.class]
- &snapshotKafkaStreamsBuilder: defined by method 'snapshotKafkaStreamsBuilder' in class path resource [com/elsevier/q2c/transaction/snapshot/builder/config/KafkaStreamsConfig.class]
```

I would expect to overcome this issue by marking one of the two StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(s) as `@Primary` (as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009501/how-to-configure-two-instances-of-kafka-streamsbuilderfactorybean-in-spring-boot)). But even if I do:

```
@Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_BUILDER_BEAN_NAME)
@Primary
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder(
        @Qualifier(KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME) KafkaStreamsConfiguration streamsConfiguration) {
    StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean = new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(streamsConfiguration);
    return streamsBuilderFactoryBean;
}

@Bean(name = SNAPSHOT_STREAMS_BUILDER_BEAN_NAME)
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean snapshotKafkaStreamsBuilder(
        @Qualifier(SNAPSHOT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME) KafkaStreamsConfiguration streamsConfiguration) {
    StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean = new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(streamsConfiguration);
    return streamsBuilderFactoryBean;
}
```

Still I am getting exactly the same error.

I am thinking that maybe the `@Primary` makes the constructed beans a Primary. Any help more than appreciated!

**EDIT**: I circumvented the issue, by removing `@EnableKafkaStreams` and `DEFAULT_STREAMS_BUILDER_BEAN_NAME`. As a result, `KafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer` does not kick in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I circumventent the issue by removing @EnableKafkaStreams (i.e. no stream beans are created automatically) and I create manually all needed ones. Looks even better if you have more than one streams as naming can be more destriptive as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why `@Primary` didn't work. I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16329).